# In React native aws-amplify Auth.signout() giving popup while doing sign-out in iOS

Tags: react-native, google-signin, aws-amplify, social-authentication, apple-login

I am using aws-amplify to authenticate a user through social platforms Facebook, Google, and Apple, through the below method:

```
 Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Facebook });
```

I am using react-native-inappbrowser-reborn.
Now when I do `Auth.signOut()` user is getting signout but showing this popup, while there is no effect to click cancel or continue on this popup.
[image: Popup]

So is there any what to not show this popup or user should sign out only when the user clicks on the Continue button on the popup?

I know there is one thing in `InAppBrowser` given below:

```
  const authSessionResult = await InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, redirectUrl, {
      ephemeralWebSession: true,
  });
```

But by using the above thing every time the user has to login into the hosted UI, I mean for example the user has to enter the email and password for Google login every time, it does not show the already login email by default. It should show a list of logged-in emails screen like below.

[image]